# How to find distinct values between 2 MongoDB collections

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have 2 MongoDb collections.

collection **A** looks like this and contain of **463M docs**

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("...")
   phone: "12345"
},
{
   _id: ObjectId("...")
   phone: "12346"
},
{
   _id: ObjectId("...")
   phone: "12347"
}
```

collection **B** looks like this and contain **475M docs**

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("...")
   phone: "12346"
},
{
   _id: ObjectId("...")
   phone: "12347"
},
{
   _id: ObjectId("...")
   phone: "12348"
}
```

Now I want to create a **C** collection which contains **only unique records from Both collections A and B**. which will look like this.

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("...")
   phone: "12345"
},
{
   _id: ObjectId("...")
   phone: "12346"
},
{
   _id: ObjectId("...")
   phone: "12347"
},
{
   _id: ObjectId("...")
   phone: "12348"
}
```

I did search and try multiple solutions.

1. using Pymongo with upsert flag true.
2. using mogodb lookup and distinct.

First solution which is using upsert flag works find but it is to much slow as my data volume is high I need to perform this task within an 1 or 2 hour.

So I need a suggestion how can I do it faster?

Comment: You could of course just get both lists and filter them within your Python program, have you considered this?

Comment: I have 64GB ram on my server I am not sure 938M million numbers will be able to fit in the memory or not.

Comment: I have done some calculation. here are these. 

-> one_number_consume_bytes : ~59
-> Total bytes : ~55342000000
-> Total KB : ~54044921.875
-> Total MB : ~52778.24401855469
-> Total GB : ~51.54125392436981

Comment: is there no way to do this as a stream as well? So you can make a new list as new entries are loaded in and checked to the existing list creating it

Comment: yes I am writting a script to do it in the batch of 50M. and using the intermediate batch results for futher calculations

Comment: Is `"phone"` the only field that makes the documents _distinct_?  I.e, the `"_id"` can be different in the new collection?  Are there any other fields in either collection that you want to preserve and store in the new collection?

Comment: I'm wondering if you could launch two simultaneous aggregation pipelines on each `A` & `B` collection that each end with a `"$merge"` onto the new `C` third collection.  It would be nice to just let the MongoDB server do all the work.

Comment: let me try your suggestion I will let you know if it works, @rickhg12hs